# Reference request: groups of order $p^4$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups, groups-enumeration

I am looking for a textbook or a paper which include the classification of groups of order $p^4$ ($p$ is prime) using generators and relations. In particular I like to understand which group $G$ "exist" for the odd $p$'s and do not exist for $p=2$.

Comment: Have you looked in Berkovich? This seems like it must be in there somewhere.

Comment: This was done by Burnside, and you can find the tables and proofs in his book "Theory of Groups of Finite Order" (which is not hard to find online).

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162977

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.00461v1 you can download the paper, which makes an easy reading.

Answer (score 0):

$(\mathbb{Z_p}\times \mathbb{Z_p} \times \mathbb{Z_p})\rtimes \mathbb{Z_p}$ with presentation $$ <a,b,c,d : a^p=b^p=c^p=d^p=e :  d^{-1}cd=cb, d^{-1}bd=ba,d^{-1}ad=a,c^{-1}bc=b,c^{-1}ac=a,b^{-1}ab=a>  $$is that group which you are finding . It exists for all primes $p>2$, but not for $p=2$. In the latter case, this presentation defines the dihedral group of order $2^3$.

Comment: To define a semidirect product you need to specify an action, which you have not done. So you have not defined a group.

Comment: @Derek I am sorry, what I mean is that you can always define action as shown in Burnside classification of groups of order $p^4$ (xv) which represents the group I have mentioned for $p>2$. But not for $p=2$.

Comment: But that's really not useful unless you tell us what the action is. Until you do that, you have not mentioned a group at all.

Comment: @Derek Is it fine now ?

Comment: Not exactly. When $p=2$, that presentation does not define a group of order $p^4$. The group it defines is the dihedral group of order 8 (not elementary abelian of order 16).

Comment: @DerekHolt I am sorry. It was my mistake.Is it okay now ? or am I missing something ?

Comment: I made a small further edit, but it is correct now.